# How to detect if emacs starts with a file?

Tags: start-up

I would like to be able to implement the following logic.

```
(if (developer-opened-file-with-emacs)
    (do nothing, get on with working as fast as possible)
    (load fancy splash screen that may take a while))
```

What would be a good way to detect this case so that I may use this to choose what kind of startup behavior to use?

Another way to say this is: Will emacs show `*scratch*` buffer once it's started.

---

Examples of opening emacs with a file include:

```
emacs somefile.txt
```

Or using elisp:

```
emacs --eval '(progn (find-file "test.txt"))'
```

---

*Note that checking `argv` isn't a good option since elisp may be used in a command line argument to open files.*

Comment: How did the developer open a file with Emacs; e.g., double-clicking on a file (with an extension associated with Emacs) from `Finder.app` on OSX and Emacs was built `--with-ns`?

Comment: Generally I don't think it should matter? To avoid ambiguity, I added examples using  argument or elisp. (not sure of other ways)

Comment: Hm, maybe your predicate is `(cl-remove-if-not #'buffer-file-name (buffer-list))`. But maybe there is some history mechanism interfering which opens the last file buffers automagically...

Comment: Checking `buffer-file-name` works as long as this isn't in the body of the `init` file (worth adding as an answer?)

Comment: @ideasman42 yes, it worth an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by @ideasman42, you can use `buffer-file-name` (both variable and function):

```
(defun tim/run-after-emacs-is-loaded ()
  (if (not buffer-file-name)
    (tim/load-session)))


(add-hook 'window-setup-hook #'tim/run-after-emacs-is-loaded)
```

Comment: thanks for this. I'm looking to replace the splash screen with showing the contents of my ~ directory. Do you have any advice why (find-file "~") in the hook doesn't do anything?